# What currency does the Google Play Store display in?

Tags: google-play-store

So, according to the [help desk (on Google)](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6220312?hl=en), it says the following:

> **Note**: You'll always see the currency you'll be charged in before you complete the transaction.

The only problem... Is, that I'm not seeing any currency changes. No prefixes (ie. A$##.##, S$##.## or U$##.##; for Australian Dollar, Singaporean Dollar or US Dollar) or anything.

[I've found instances where people are seeing two different currencies](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/help/google-play-store-currency-check-buying-t2979105); one before purchase and another after the purchase (in their current country's currency).

For example (Before purchase screen):
[image]

(Confirm purchase screen)
[image]

---

For me, it however... It does not change, so - I have no clue which currency it is actually showing prices in.

(Before purchase screen)
[image]

(Confirm purchase screen)
[image]

As for through an actual Android device, it only displays the amount and not the currency.
[image]

## tl;dr - The question is:

Looking at all these pictures, will I be charged:

- $2.33AUD? (Currency of credit card)
- $2.33USD? (Assumption that Google is using *its* own currency)
- $2.33SGD? (Currency of location; where I am)

Also, as usual - The above costs does not include processing/conversion fees and charges, and other stuffs and whatnot that goes behind the scenes that ends up getting lumped onto your bill.

Comment: Probably depends on the region settings of the device. This needs some research (or it might just be a Google error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay now I just checked the same app here as you can see:

[image]

So it shows the price in my local currency.

I also checked that 4.78 TL is equal to 2.33 AUD, so that **price you see there is in AUD.**

Comment: What did you mean by "here" in your answer? I'll have a similar problem since I'm in Brazil and I have an American (USD) card.

Comment: @VitorCanova I don't understand what you need to figure out. When you check the app, it shows it in your local currency.

Comment: Right. I need the opposite. I need see and pay in USD.

Comment: @VitorCanova To see the opposite, you can use any currency converter. Even Google itself has one. Just search *BRL to USD* on Google. You can pay with your credit card regardless of its currency. For example: If it says app is 30 BRL, it means it is 9,25 USD. When you pay with your credit card, it should charge you 9,25 USD.