# wrong currency in my playstore account

Tags: google-play-games

When I tried to make a purchase from HOF I found out that the reason the prices were incorrect was because they were in the wrong currency.  When I checked my account it said canadian which is correct.  What do I do to correct this issue?

Comment: Related [what-currency-does-the-google-play-store-display-in](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129503/what-currency-does-the-google-play-store-display-in)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your network/gps location is correct, then clear app data.

I had a similar issue with Google Maps (hotel price in foreign currency) after international travel.